# Log4j2: Programmatically create file appender with timestamp in the filename

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

There is a possibility to create to add a timestamp to log4j2 logging files using [property] configuration:

```
appender.FILE.type = FILE
appender.FILE.name = FILE
appender.FILE.fileName = file-with-date-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log
appender.FILE.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.FILE.layout.pattern =[%p] %m%n
```

This will produce log files in the `file-with-date-2017-11-30.log`. How can I achieve the same behavior using programmatic configuration? This is what I have tried so far:

```
PatternLayout layout = PatternLayout.newBuilder()
            .withConfiguration(ctx.getConfiguration())
            .withPattern("%m%n").build();

FileAppender fileAppender = FileAppender.newBuilder()
        .withLayout(layout)
        .withFileName( "file-with-date-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log")
        .withName("pattern")
        .build();
```

But this produces the following file: `file-with-date-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log`. So using properties configuration: a log file with current date is crated, using programmatically created appender `${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log` gets ignored.

Comment: Why go through all that when you can use a `RollingFileAppender` with a timebase policy?

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently [StrSubstitutor](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/StrSubstitutor.html) can help in this situation.

```
final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
String fileName = config.
              getStrSubstitutor().replace("file-with-date-${date:yyyy-MM-dd}.log");

FileAppender fileAppender = FileAppender.newBuilder()
        .withLayout(layout)
        .withFileName(filename)
        .withName("pattern")
        .build();
```